# C# Database Compact connection error

Tags: c#, database

Im testing out some database compact code using a simple form to add data to a database.
When I click the AddBtn, all I want is to insert some values from text fields into my database but instead I get this error "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0." And the problem seems to be within the SqlCeConnection row.

Complete code sample:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.Sql;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
        InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void AddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"C:\Users\Name\Documents\Visual Studio         2012\Projects\DataBaseTest\MyDatabase#1.sdf");
                try {
                    con.Open();

                    SqlCeCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

                    cmd.CommandText = "insert into test ([ID], [OrderID], [KundID]) values('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"')";

                    try {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using a valid connection string (add `'Data Source='` before the path to the SDF.
See the MSDN documentation for `SqlCeConnection`.

```
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Name\Documents\Visual Studio         2012\Projects\DataBaseTest\MyDatabase#1.sdf"
```

Other than that do not use the text of the buttons directly in the query (leaves you open to SQL injection attack) use SQL parameters instead (again MSDN is your friend.)

Comment: Ah, tried using Data Source earlier cause thats what the "connection string" was supposed to be according to VS12.. must have been some other error back then, thanks for clearing it out, works perfect :) and I am aware of injections but all I want is a working database for the time being, as Im new to all this.

Answer (score 5):

Yes your connection string is wrong.
Look here http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-ce

The corrected one should be

```
 string pathSDF = @"C:\Users\Name\Documents\Visual Studio 2012" + 
                   "\Projects\DataBaseTest\MyDatabase#1.sdf";
 SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" + pathSDF + 
                                           ";Persist Security Info=False;");
```

Aside from that, your SQL command is really dangerous. You should never write sql command concatenating strings taken directly from the user input. This leads to [Sql Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
Change your code to: (I assume that your ID fields are of numeric type and not varchars)

```
  cmd.CommandText = "insert into test ([ID], [OrderID], [KundID]) values " + 
                    "(@userID, @orderID, @kundID)";  

  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderID", Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text));
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kundID", Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text));
```

Comment: Yeh, I'm aware of injections, just testing it out for the time being, was planning on looking this up in the future but thanks for the info :)